# How to install FontAwesome 5 in Angular + ASP.NET Core v2 Project Setup

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, font-awesome-5

I am looking to find an answer to how FontAwesome 5 should work with ASP.NET Core v2 default Angular application (Code Generated with .NET Core CLI).

webpack.config.vendor.js

```
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome',
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome/styles.css',
    'zone.js',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
];
```

I can also see the fontawesome added to `vendor.js` and `vendor.css` files, but when I add `<i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i>` to the HTML it is not being replaced with SVG.

Answer (score 0):

`@fortawesome/fontawesome` is the base package. You have to install at least one further package on the base page. You can term it as an add-on package.

```
Free Solid   ||  $ npm i -s @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
Free Regular ||  $ npm i -s @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular
Free Brands  ||  $ npm i -s @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands
```

For an example. Install `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid`

And add it in `nonTreeShakableModules`.

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
     ...
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome',
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid',
     ...
];
```

(I don't know it is Tree Shakable or not. If it's then put the files into `treeShakableModules`)

---

If you're worried about build size (yes, if it's not Tree Shakable), you can import only those SVG which you need.

For an example, if you `fa-camera-retro` need, import `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faCameraRetro` only.

---

Reference: [Offical Document](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/js-component-packages)

Comment: this did not work as explained.  i can see the icon is added to `vendor.js`, but the `<i>` element still remains in the document.

Comment: In console, if you type `fontawesome`, what is showing? undefined?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be helpful, but depending on what you're trying to do, your current method may be overkill. Including Font Awesome 5 according to the docs is for using the font resources directly in your node.js app. That may not be what you're actually looking for here. If you just want a local copy of the CSS/JS to reference in your web application's HTML, it's better to pull from their [already-compiled Github project](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome).

This is not an npm package (no package.json), so if you want to use npm to pull it, you'll need [napa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/napa). Then, just edit your application's package.json and add/change the line in the `"scripts"` section:

```
"install": "napa FortAwesome/Font-Awesome"
```

Then, when you `npm install`, the compiled version of Font Awesome will be pulled down into your `node_modules` directory. All you need to do then, is use webpack or similar to move the static resources you need to `wwwroot/lib` or wherever you're serving them from.